# Solr nested object schema design

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a following json document to commit in solr:

```
  {
    "threadId":"1",
    "app":"application-name",
    "server":"server-name",
    "loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog",
    "level":"INFO",
    "endOfBatch":"false",
    "thrown": {
        "commonElementCount": 0,
        "localizedMessage": "private accessor [email]",
        "message": "private accessor [email]",
        "name": "org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.PrivateAccessorException",
        "extendedStackTrace": "org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.Priv.."
    },
    "message":"Starting MonitorApiApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 1 (/opt/app/monitor-api.jar started by root in /opt/app)",
    "threadPriority":"5",
    "user":"test",
    "timeMillis":"1697531693066",
    "UNIQUE_ID":"e31bbf2c-2b19-4d41-9d4e-ce44c95df667",
    "_version_":"1779990992732028928",
    "_root_":"e31bbf2c-2b19-4d41-9d4e-ce44c95df667"
}
```

I need to create a solr schema with nested document.
I've searched the web, but there is no example of managed-schema with nested documents.

Any help is appreciated.

I've tried using solr cloud and schema designer but it is not working.

Comment: Have you had a look at this : https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html